# SSIS - How do I see/set the field types in a Recordset?

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis, types, recordset

I'm looking at an inherited SSIS package, and a stored procedure is sending records to a recordset called USER:NEW_RECORDS.  It's of type Object, and the value is System.Object.  It is then used for inputting that data to a SQL table.  We're getting an error, because it seems that the numeric results of the stored procedure are being put in a DT_WSTR field, and then failing when it is then put into a decimal field in the database.

Most of the records are working, but one, which happens to have a longer number of decimal digits, is failing.

I want to see exactly what my SSIS recordset field types are, and probably change them, so I can force the data to be truncated properly and copied.  Or, perhaps, I'm not even looking at this correctly.  The data is put into the recordset using a SQL Task that executes the stored procedure.

Edit: It appears that this particular recordset is used twice, and this is the second use of it.  I'm thinking that perhaps it has the data types of the first use.  But I can't put a Data Viewer on a SQL Task, can I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am having the same trouble, so I directed the flow behind the record set into a flat file.

Answer (score 0):

I did make a new recordset to use, so that the other one was not used.  And while I never did figure out how to see the data, I could change the data types of the types in the parameter mapping, which was apparently what was needed.  I changed a type from NUMERIC to FLOAT, and it quit complaining about some of the data.

This question may be too specific to my own problem to be of use to others.  I may delete it.